# how to display vbulletin posts in php homepage?

Tags: php, vbulletin

i want to display my vbulletin posts in my php homepage

example:

title
username, date
description
link (details)

> title 
>   username, date 
>   description 
>   details

Comment: search for the table that handles vbulletin posts, and then connect the database and retrieve the data you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VBulletin has a beautifull API start there:
[vB API](https://members.vbulletin.com/api/)